# VSTO Outlook: Execute default Outlook behavior for all folder events apart from the custom code

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-interop, office-addins

I have an Outlook Add-in in which I subscribe to ItemAdd event and some others for all the folders in the folder tree.

Within those events I place custom code but I am wondering if I am altering the current Outlook behavior for those folders events.

So is there any way for all the folders I subscribe to ItemAdd or some other events to tell Outlook to execute the default behavior (like when you call a base method) for those events apart from executing the custom code I have put inside those events?

Comment: Could you be more specific - what exactly do you have in the `ItemAdd` event handler and how it prevents from executing the default actions?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I am not preventing the execution of the default actions. I only wanted to know if the default behavior is always executed despite of the logic I put within those  folder events. What i have observed is that if I subscribe to those events for Outbox folder, then if i try to send a new message, the message is not sent nor stored in sent ítems folder instead it is stored in the Outbox folder even if in the AddItem event i don't do anything in cas of Outbox folder. Why?

Comment: Don't touch items in the Outbox folder because such actions may cause items to be stuck in the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ItemAdd` doesn't let you cancel the default action. The default behavior will be executed anyway.

To prevent the default behavior the event handler should provide a special parameter for that. For example, the [ItemSend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.itemsend) event handler provides the `cancel` parameter which is `false` when the event occurs. If the event procedure sets this argument to `true`, the send action is not completed and the inspector is left open.